# Why does navigate() fail at one customer site when it works at all others?

Tags: javascript, html

We have a C++ application that uses a WebBrowser control to display information to the user.  The application, the HMTL screens and the Javascript files used by the screens are very similar but not necessarily identical for all customers.  Here is the [first screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RHTS.jpg) seen by our users.  Each rectangle is an HTML element dynamically created by a Javascript function.  When a user double-clicks a rectangle, a screen with details about the selected base is supposed to appear.  This has been working at all of our customers for many years, but it doesn't work for our new customer.  It works on my computer using the same screens and database that the customer has.  At our new customer's site, when the user double-clicks a base box, the C++ application crashes.

When a user double-clicks on a rectangle, the BaseUpdate_Click() method is called.  Here it is:

```
    function BaseDisplay_Click() {
        var BaseId;

        //var NewString;

        //NewString = LanguageCtrl.TranslateString("lbs");
        alert("BaseDisplay_Click");

        BaseId = window.event.srcElement.BaseId;
      alert("Trying to display base " + BaseId);
        if (BaseId == undefined) 
      {       
        BaseId = window.event.srcElement.parentElement.BaseId;
        alert ("BaseId was unknown.  Now it is " + BaseId);
      }

        WriteCookie("leavebaseupdate", 1); 
        WriteCookie("base", BaseId);
        WriteCookie("currentview", CurrentView);
        WriteCookie("myarea", MyArea);
        WriteCookie("mystatus", MyStatus);
        WriteCookie("statusvalue", StatusValue);
        WriteCookie("OverviewView", CurrentView);
        alert("About to navigate to baseupdate.htm");
      try
      {
              navigate("BaseUpdate.htm");
      }
      catch (e)
      {
        alert ("Failed to navigate to baseupdate.htm: " + e.message);
      }
    }
```

The "About to navigate to baseupdate.htm" message appears as expected, but then the C++ application crashes.  I added the exception handler to try to see what was happening, but the handler is never executed.

I tried changing "baseupdate.htm" to "ThisDoesNotExist.htm" and got the same behavior.  I tried using a full path to baseupdatehtm, and still got the same behavior.  I commented out the call to navigate() to verify that the problem is in one of the screens and not in the C++ application.  As expected, the C++ application continued running.

It is possible for me replace the call to navigate() with the addition of an  element to the dynamically generated base elements.  If I were to do that, would the double-click handler that calls BaseDisplay_Click() still get executed to write the cookies that baseupdate.htm needs?  If not, what would be the best way to pass those values to baseupdate.htm?

Comment: is `navigate()` declared somewhere? I mean, if you want to change page, `window.location.href = 'BaseUpdate.htm'` should work fine in JS

Comment: Thank you for your response.  From what I've just read, window.navigate() is a function available in most browsers but not all.  I've been trying various versions of window.location, window.location.href, document.location and document.location.href, with no success so far.

Comment: I tried navigating to the current page, replacing the navigate() call with "window.location.html = window.location.html".  My application still crashed.  On the way out, it reports an error code of C0000005.

Comment: just out of curiousity, if you declare in your page `<a href="BaseUpdate.html">manually navigate</a>` can you reach the detsination by clicking on it?

Comment: You need to debug your C++ since it's where the crash happens. Check what's happening before the error and what's different at this user calls. Your JS is working fine, the problem must lie in the information provided to the background application.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not related to HTML or Javascript.  The page I was navigating to uses an ActiveX control that hadn't been registered.